# Retrieving data from two different tables with common column using left outer join and on clause

Tags: mysql, left-join

Guys I have two different tables.

Table-1:

```
contract-id | contract-date
  1         | 01-05-2016
  1         | 01-06-2016
  1         | 01-07-2016
  2         | 01-01-2016
  2         | 01-02-2016
  3         | 01-05-2016
  3         | 01-06-2016
```

Table-2:

```
invoice-number|contract-id|invoice-from-date|invoice-to-date
 1            |1          |01-05-2016       |31-05-2016
 2            |1          |15-05-2016       |31-05-2016
 3            |1          |25-05-2016       |31-05-2016
```

My requirement is, I have to show what are all the contracts that comes in the current month from table-1 and I have to show the count of the invoice raised for those contracts from table-2. If there are any invoice raised, it should show its count or simply zero. The expected answer is:

```
contract-id|counts
 1         |3
 3         |0
```

The count for contract-id: 1 is 3, because I've raised three invoices for the current month and the count for contract-id: 3 is 0, because I haven't raised any invoice for it. And contract-id:2 is missing , because, it does not come under current month.

This is what I've tried:

```
    select cbm_contract_period_value_split.contract_id,
count(cbm_contract_invoice_request.contract_id),
cbm_contract_period_value_split.contract_date
from cbm_contract_period_value_split
left outer join cbm_contract_invoice_request
on cbm_contract_period_value_split.contract_id = cbm_contract_invoice_request.contract_id
and MONTH(cbm_contract_period_value_split.contract_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
and MONTH(cbm_contract_invoice_request.invoice_for_the_period_of_from_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

I've already posted this question, but now I'm posting this with an edited version with the answers I got. Yet, I'm not getting the desired answer. What's wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Why did contract id #2 disappear in your desired result when #3 is still there?

Comment: That is just a simple example and it need not be considered because, it is not in the current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one. I think you need a GROUP BY and I put in the WHERE to filter out the rows that aren't current month.

```
select pvs.contract_id,
       count(ir.contract_id) as counts,
       pvs.contract_date
from cbm_contract_period_value_split as pvs
left join cbm_contract_invoice_request as ir
on pvs.contract_id = ir.contract_id
and MONTH(ir.invoice_for_the_period_of_from_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
WHERE MONTH(pvs.contract_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY pvs.contract_id,pvs.contract_date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5f08c/9

result

```
contract_id     counts  contract_date
1               3       May, 01 2016 00:00:00
3               0       May, 01 2016 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table-1.contract_id, Table-1.contract-date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Table-2 LEFT JOIN Table-1 ON Table-1.contract_id =  Table-2.contract_id WHERE MONTH(Table-1.contract-date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY Table-1.contract_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query..

```
SELECT 
  t1.`contract-id`,
  (    
    CASE      
      WHEN t2.`contract-id` IS NULL 
      THEN 0 
      ELSE COUNT(*) 
    END
  ) AS counts 
FROM
  t1 
  LEFT JOIN t2 
    ON t1.`contract-id` = t2.`contract-id` 
WHERE MONTH(`contract-date`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY t2.`contract-id` 
ORDER BY t1.`contract-id`,`contract-date` ;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39893/2)**